# Jquery Slider and Jquery autocomplete

Tags: mysql, jquery-ui, jquery, slider

I Have Been working on a page the using a jquery autocomplete so that while your typing in a clients name its searching the databases for any macth containing that phrase. so using "LIKE" .
i have also put together a jquery silder so that it displays the records that are automaticly loaded from the database and when u click on one it will load more inofmation from the database..

indivaully thesse 2 pieces of code work fine so the jquery autocomplete on a serprate page just loading text enterys from a database. 
and the jquery slider works fine with manually entered data and data loaded by php from a database..

but when i put them together the problem is it shows the record on the screen with the styling from the jquery slider but when u click the record it doesnt show anything so no slider (atm just manual html data in the slider for testing)

i have tried multipule tests such as running them serpeatre, placing them in different div  tags. i have got it to work with a single sql query but it isnt what i need to do because i dont want the page to need to be refreshed for loading data.

i have placed my code from both files so th is first one is what calls the ajax request to create the records..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $(".recordrow").click(function() {
        var divid = "details-" + $(this).attr('id').split("-")[1]; //Create the id of the div
        $("#"+divid).show().animate({ "right": '0%'}); //Bring the div from right to left with 200px padding from the screen
    });

    $('#bt-close').click(function(){
     $('.details').animate({right:-2000}, 500);

    });

    });


    function getStates(value){

    $.post("sql.php",{partialState:value},function(data){
    $("#results").html(data);
    });
    }
    </script> 

    <input type="text" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)"/>
    <br />
    <div id="results">

    </div>
```

And this is the page which querys the database

```
<?php 
if($_POST['partialState']){
mysql_connect("localhost","root")or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ict_devices") or die (mysql_error());

$test=$_POST['partialState'];
$text="... More details of the records";

$states = mysql_query("Select * from students Where FirstName LIKE '%$test%'");

while($state= mysql_fetch_array($states)){
echo '<div class="recordrow" id="row-$state["id"]">'.$state['FirstName'].'</div>';
echo '<div class="details" id="details-$state["id"]">'.$text.'<a href="#" id="bt-close">Close</a></div>';
}
}
?>
```

any help would be greatly appricated

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind a click function on "recordrow" div after you got it by ajax. In your code there are no "recordrows" on the moment a click event binds. So you need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStates(value){
        $.post("sql.php", function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
            $('.recordrow').each(function() {
               $(this).bind('click', function() {
                   var divid = "details-" + $(this).attr('id').split("-")[1]; //Create the id of the div
                   $("#"+divid).show().animate({ "right": '0%'}); //Bring the div from right to left with 200px padding from the screen
               });
            });
            $('#bt-close').each(function() {
                $(this).bind('click', function(){
                    $('.details').animate({right:-2000}, 500);
                });

            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Your ajax is right and when you test slider recordrows already in DOM, click binds correcly. That is why it works by parts

**EDIT:** I test my code and add binding of bt-close event, it works for me, try it. It shows details when clicked and animation launches

Comment: i  placed the code where it should go but i still am having no success.. i was thining if i placed an onclick function on the div the stores the record to trigger the slider to come out.. would that work and if so how would i do it ?

Comment: You use jQuery 1.3, which is ok for previous version of jQuery UI. What version of jQueryUI do you use? I would not surprised you use conflicting versions of both autocomplete and slider.

Comment: jquery 1.3.2 is there newer or ? and do i need to inculde the jquery ui libary into this to get it to work ?

Comment: I have tried this code now multipul times and i have not been able to get it to work at all... its bringing up an error saying its not posting any varibles across and when i edit the frist line to work like this   $.post("sql.php",{partialState:value},function(data){ i then get another error sayng the line with var divid is not working...